# How to develop an iphone application on Windows OS?

Tags: ios, windows

How to develop an iPhone application without using Mac OS?
Is it possible to develop an application on Windows XP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a mac to develop for iOS devices. Here is a quote from the Apple website with the specifics:

> To develop with iOS SDK and participate in the iOS Developer Program you must have an Intel-based Mac running Mac OS X Snow Leopard. Refer to the iOS SDK Read Me document for full details on system requirements. You must be registered as an Apple Developer in order to access the iOS SDK and iOS SDK Read Me document.

You can read the full details on the [Apple iOS dev site here](http://developer.apple.com/support/resources/ios-dev-center.html).

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.

i seen this link,

http://www.taranfx.com/how-to-develop-iphone-apps-on-windows

they said few methods,

How about these methods?

Comment: Ok. 
Which one is better option?

Comment: My opinion is that going through Apple and their dev program and SDK is the best option. You have less of a change of getting your app denied during approval. You also have a much larger support base for asking questions since the objective c and iOS community is growing very fast.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible build a iphone application by using java and LWUIT framework?